# Hibernate listeners are not getting invoked in Spring JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, junit

I'm creating Spring MVC application with Hibernate as the data access layer. All my entities contain `createdOn` and `updatedOn` fields, which contain timestamps when the entity was created/updated. The `createdOn` field is set using `PreInsertEventListener` and the `updatedOn` field is set using `PreUpdateEventListener`.

When I run my application, it works as expected, listeners are registered and when I save an entity, appropriate listeners are invoked (verified using debugger). But when I try to unit test this behavior, the listeners are registered, but never invoked.

I determined using debugging that when I save an entity in my application `EntityInsertAction#preInsert` is invoked, which loops through the registered listeners and invokes them. But when I run my unit test this method is never invoked.

Here is an example of my unit test:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        BaseConfiguration.class,
        DatabaseConfiguration.class
})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class HibernateListenerTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooDao fooDao;

    @Test
    public void testPreUpdateListener() {
        Foo foo = fooDao.merge(createFoo());
        Assert.assertNotNull(foo.getCreatedOn());
        Assert.assertNull(foo.getUpdatedOn());

        foo.setBar("Bar");
        foo = fooDao.merge(foo);
        Assert.assertNotNull(foo.getUpdatedOn());
    }

}
```

Because the listeners are not invoked the unit tests always fail with the following exception:

`org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value`

So my question is: why is this behavior different between running the application and running the unit test and if there is a way to fix the code so that the listeners are correctly invoked in my unit tests?

Thanks in advance for any input. Please leave a comment if additional code/information is needed.

Comment: Did you debug your test case and see if EntityInsertAction#preInsert is invoked? If it is does then are the listeners registered? If so, does the code loop through and call them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are testing Hibernate listeners, just call [`Session#flush`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush%28%29) manually before your assertions.

Just let Spring inject `SessionFactory` into your test and do `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();`.

If you want your listeners to act before the session is being flushed, then you need to use different event (e.g. MERGE or PERSIST).